# Command to Get Security Audit settings

Tags: windows, group-policy, audit

Im looking to retrieve the Security audit configuration on a domain joined PC which has audit settings applied Via a domain GPO, but im getting - what seems to be - conflicting results. If i run an RSOP, i see the aduting settings, but `Auditpol /get /category:"Logon/Logoff"` shows No Auditing. Likewise the local security policy UI, or an secedit export all show No Auditing (AuditLogonEvents = 0). See screenshot below. I know there's a legacy and advanced version of auditing which could be determined by the `SCENoApplyLegacyAuditPolicy` reg key under `HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\LSA` but i dont see the key at all on this machine in question. How could i accurately fetch the auditing settings under any scenario?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Auditpol is for Advanced Audit Policy settings.

The policy settings configured in the screenshot are legacy audit policy settings. To view those use:

```
secedit /export /areas SECURITYPOLICY /cfg Filename.txt
```

[image: Advanced Audit Policy Configuration]

Comment: Hi Greg, I added a second screenshot which shows that the secedit export is also showing no auditing.

Comment: If you want to use legacy audit policies, the registry value needs to be set to 0.

Comment: So if i understand you correctly, unless i've got the reg setting set, the audit settings showing in RSOP are not actually applied?

Comment: Correct. This has been a well known issue for a long time and is documented here: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/921468/security-auditing-settings-are-not-applied-to-windows-vista-based-and .